# How to install requests-ntlm2 in the virtual machine?

Tags: django

I could not install the requests-ntlm2 package for API integration in my Django project (python2.7.17).

Error:

> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f7c928569d0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/requests-ntlm2/
> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f7c92856880>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/requests-ntlm2/
> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f7c92856610>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/requests-ntlm2/
> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f7c928565b0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/requests-ntlm2/
> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f7c928564f0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/requests-ntlm2/
> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement requests-ntlm2 (from versions: none)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for requests-ntlm2

Comment: That's related to your network connection. Please post the error as text next time.

Comment: I can install it on my local machine but not in the VM. The network bandwidth is good. I just wonder what's wrong.

Comment: You never said there's a VM involved. Anyway, for some reason the VM can't connect to pypi.org – fix that.

Comment: It seems that the VM is not connected to the "outside" world. It may be connected to a virtual network (e.g. host, or vm-only network). You could download the file(s) and do a `pip install <package> ...`

Comment: Thanks, but I tried installing it on my local machine and shared it via email. Then I connected the VM, downloaded it from my email, and put it in the path where all my packages had been placed. It worked. Even it is there when I print pip freeze.